# How to match dot in macro and reconstruct original set of tokens?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to write a macro that will expand this:

```
let res = log_request_response!(client.my_call("friend".to_string(), 5));
```

Into this:

```
let res = {
    debug!("Request: {}", args_separated_by_commas);
    let res = client.my_call("friend".to_string(), 5);
    debug!("Response: {}", res);
    res
};
```

My attempt so far is something like this:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! log_request_response_to_scuba {
    ($($client:ident)?.$call:ident($($arg:expr),*);) => {
        let mut s = String::new();
        $(
            {
                s.push_str(&format!("{:?}, ", $arg));
            }
        )*
        s.truncate(s.len() - 2);
        debug!("Request: {}", s);
        // Somehow reconstruct the entire thing with res = at the start.
        debug!("Response: {}", res);
        res
    };
}
```

But this fails to compile:

```
error: macro expansion ignores token `{` and any following
  --> src/main.rs:10:13
   |
10 |             {
   |             ^
...
39 |     let res = log_request_response_to_scuba!(client.my_call(hey, 5));
   |               ------------------------------------------------------ caused by the macro expansion here
   |
   = note: the usage of `log_request_response_to_scuba!` is likely invalid in expression context
```

If I remove the `.` in between the `client` and `call` match it throws a different error about an ambiguous match (which makes sense).

So my first nitty gritty question is how do I match a dot? To me this match looks correct but apparently not.

Beyond that any help with making a macro that does what I want would be great. If it were a regex I'd just want this:

```
.*\((.*)\).*
```

Where I just capture the stuff inside the parentheses and split them. Then I use the 0th capture group to get the whole thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is not because you are matching the dot somehow wrong, but because you are not returning an expression. You want to return this:

```rust
{
    debug!("Request: {}", args_separated_by_commas);
    let res = client.my_call("friend".to_string(), 5);
    debug!("Response: {}", res);
    res
};
```

However, your macro currently returns something more akin to this:

```rust
debug!("Request: {}", args_separated_by_commas);
let res = client.my_call("friend".to_string(), 5);
debug!("Response: {}", res);
res
```

Note the missing curly braces. This can be remedied quite easily by enclosung the complete transcriber part in braces.

---

I am not sure why `client` is optional in your matcher. I assume that you want to optionally allow the user of the macro to either call a function or a method on some variable. Is that correct? If yes, then your code currently does not allow that – it matches `client.my_call(...)` as well as `.some_function(...)`, but NOT `some_function(...)` (note the removed space from the beginning). To do what you want, you could match on `$variable:ident$(.$field:ident)?` – note that the dot is here optional as well – or even better `$variable:ident$(.$field:ident)*` to allow to call a method on a field of a field of a loval variable (so, something like `variable.sub_struct.do_something()`.

---

The resulting code with some examples:

```rust
macro_rules! log_request_response {
    ($variable:ident$(.$field:ident)*($($arg:expr),*)) => {
        {
            let mut s = String::new();
            $(
                {
                    s.push_str(&format!("{:?}, ", $arg));
                }
            )*
            s.truncate(s.len() - 2);
            // using println! here because I don't want to set up logging infrastructure
            println!("Request: {}", s);
            let res = $variable$(.$field)*($($arg),*);
            println!("Response: {}", res);
            res
        }
    };
}

fn test_func(_: String, i: i32) -> i32 {
    i
}

struct TestStruct;

impl TestStruct {
    fn test_method(&self, _: String, i: i32) -> i32 {
        i
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _ = log_request_response!(TestStruct.test_method("friend".to_string(), 5));
    let _ = log_request_response!(test_func("friend".to_string(), 5));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eee3a5fd83e7427060d896369b4f1d7b)

Comment: Wow thanks so much, I love the Rust community. I really thought the first set of curly braces was the curly braces enclosing what I returned, silly mistake. Thanks for getting the whole thing to work!